# Facebook iPhone App Livefeed page, is it a UIWebView or a complex UITableView

Tags: iphone, facebook

I wonder how they make the username, URL to be special colored and also tap on them will navigate user to different pages. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook iPhone app uses a few custom subclasses of for example `UITableView` to accomplish what it does. Take a look at [the Three20 project page](http://github.com/facebook/three20) where a lot of the classes are available for your use.

Comment: yep, that's pretty good set of classes. if there are some tutorials out there to showcase the usage of the classes, that'll be fantastic